# mime-тип файла из его расширения

Tags: java, android, mime

Как определить mime-тип файла из его расширения?

Comment: В общем случае никак. Расширение - штука в общем отфонарная.

Comment: @Akina А тогда вообще как его можно узнать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берём список официально зарегистрированных в IANA.ORG [Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Хардкодим. Ищем расширение конкретного файла в таблице, получаем MIME type.

Answer (score 1):

> В общем случае никак. Расширение - штука в общем отфонарная

Вы уверены @Akina?

Есть [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) - там достаточно просто можно получить mime тип из любого расширения. Примеров в сети много - гугль в помощь

Если речь идет об Android, то тут еще проще - есть стандартный класс [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html):

```
  String mimeType=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
```

Comment: RTFM: *String: A file extension without the leading '.'*

Comment: Сначало думал всё норм, но потом обнаружал, что файлы с русским названием неопределяет

Comment: Да, уверен. Потому как ЛЮБОМУ файлу я имею право дать ЛЮБОЕ расширение. И чхать мне на то, что там у файла внутри. Иными словами, расширение максимум говорит "существует вероятность, что", но при этом никаких гарантий. И вообще расширение - это не отдельная сущность, а просто кусочек имени после последней точки, если таковая имеется (а если не имеется - то расширение пустое, ну или можно сказать что отсутствует), и ориентироваться на него ненамного надёжнее, чем, скажем, говорить, что если имя файла начинается с wp_ , то это стопудово файл от вордпресса.

Comment: @Akina ни разу не сомневаюсь в ваших способностях чхать на что угодно и на кого угодно :) Речь шла о том, что любому *начиханному* расширению всегда соответствует некий mime тип (речь не о контенте, а о декларации контента, коим и является mime тип)

Comment: @Barmaley Заявленный АВТОРОМ вопрос просит _определить mime-тип файла из его расширения_. Конкретного файла. Я утверждаю, что между "должен быть согласно расширению" и "есть на самом деле" - в реальности может быть дистанция огромного размера. А может и не быть. Если эти два варианта совпадают - я дал ссылку на соответствие. Если  не совпадают - указал в комментарии. Что же пытаетесь утверждать Вы - я понять не могу. Соглашаетесь с одним из этих вариантов? или пытаетесь описАть некий упущенный мной третий? "MIME-тип соответствует содержимому, а не расширению" - хотя бы это не оспаривается?

Comment: Ну если мы не рассматриваем ситуацию когда файл JPEG переименован с расширением TXT, то любому расширению всегда соответствует mime тип - разве не так? Я именно это и утверждал.

Comment: _любому расширению всегда соответствует mime тип - разве не так?_ ЭТО - верно. Я же говорю о том, что есть три компонента - расширение, содержимое, MIME-тип. Соответственно три попарные связи, из которых только одна указанная - абсолютна (при условии что расширение официально зарегистрировано).